# How to programmatically hide XML in java (JAXB)

Tags: java, xml

I have a use case where in some cases (dependant on business logic) we want to not display some XML elements.  So I can't use @XmlTransient (i think).

I'd like to do something like this.

```
private void HideSome() {
 // some code to hide a specific element

}
```

Comment: Can you give more information? For example, code you have tried, what results you encountered so far. This is an vary general vague question at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the element not required in annotations and the corresponding XSD as optional (minOccurs=0 maxOccurs=1).

If you do not want it rendered, set it to null before passing it to the marshaller.

xsd

```
<complexType name="MyElementType">
  <sequence>
    <element name="ID" type="string" />
    <element name="MaybeHere" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  </sequence>
</complexType>
<element name="MyElement" type="MyElementType" />
```

java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="MyElement")
public class MyElement {
  private String id;
  private String maybeHere;

  @XmlElement(name="ID")
  public String getId() {return id;}
  public void setId(String s){this.id = s;}

  @XmlElement(name="MaybeHere", required=false)
  public String getMaybeHere() {return maybeHere;}
  public void setMaybeHere(String s) { this.maybeHere = s;}
}
```

marshalling

```
/* in some code */
if(businessCondition){
  myElem.maybeHere = null;

}
marshaller.marshal(myElem);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very detailed and I appreciate it.  It broke in the following scenario:  BigDecimal foo was initialized to 0.00.    Then depending on business logic we were not going to use it - set it to null.  Convert to JSON, works fine, no value is set.  Then convert to XML using this code:  MyObj object = gson.fromJson(jsonstr, MyObj.class); - I think this reinitializes it so that null values are populated with 0.  So the workaround is not initialize to 0.00, init to null.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If a value is considered optional, I would only initialize it when needed.

Comment: In hindsight the other thing I realized is that we were doing an unnecessary transform from object -> json -> xml.  So, this helped save processing time.   Thanks!